# Custom MKAnnotationView -- how wire up text field, button with properties?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I am making a custom callout (of MKAnnotationView class) so a user can tap on the map and enter in some information in the callout. I need to wire up the text field and button on the callout somewhere so the data can be passed.

I'm stuck on how to connect the textfield and button with a properties in a view controller. I don't know where I would connect them -- the map view controller would make some sense, but the view they belong to is a UIView, not a UIViewController. I am familiar with connecting outlets and actions with a view controller, but this is something I haven't done before.

Here are the options I've tinkered with thus far. Which one would be best? Or is there a better way?

Option 1:

Make a UIView in a storyboard with same class as my MKAnnotationView, and link up the labels and buttons to the parent view controller.

Problem: I get this message before my ViewForAnnotation even gets called:

```
UITextField stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b54ab0
```

It is coming from the textField property I set in the view controller.

Option 2:

Build it all dynamically when I call the ViewForAnnotation method in the view controller. Init with frame that I set, add buttons and textboxes programmatically.

Problem: How do I wire the textbox's text to a property? And where should I wire it?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding option 1,

`UITextField` doesn't have any method called `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`.

This is a method of `NSString`. `UITextField` has a `text` property to get its text string, so you would actually want to call this method like this for example:

```
UITextField *myTextField = ... ;
NSString *text = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me identify the source of the error. Do you know how I could wire up my annotation view with properties? This is where I'm stuck.